# Sharing a folder using sharepoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, java

Do you have an idea how to share a folder with a list of users(list of emails) using Sharepoint Rest Api from a java application?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

_api/SP.Web.CreateOrganizationSharingLink could generate share link in orgnization(no specific users).

[image]

If you want to specify the user, you could use below endpoint to assign permission to folder directly.

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/lee/MyDoc/subfolder')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=13,roleDefId=1073741830)
```

Comment: Thanks so to share a folder with users i should make two steps: generating a sharing link then adding permissions. I can't do this in one call? for the users i have only their emails.